# Generic interface of an interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Foreword: Title may not state the real problem I am having. I just don´t know I could express my problem in a better and short way.

I have a question regarding generic interface implementation in C# regarding the following structure:

```
public interface ITransition
{
    IState<ITransition> SourceState { get; }

    IState<ITransition> DestinationState { get; }
}

public interface IState<T> where T : ITransition
{
    List<T> Transitions { get; }

    StateType StateType { get; }
}
```

And the following implementation of `IState` interface:

```
public class FieldState : IState<FieldTransition>
```

Then I want such an implementation of `ITransition`:

```
public class FieldTransition : ITransition
{
    public IState<ITransition> SourceState { get;  }

    public IState<ITransition> DestinationState { get;  }

    private IIntent ConditionalIntent { get; }

    public FieldTransition(FieldState sourceState, FieldState destinationState,
        IIntent conditionalIntent)
    {
        SourceState = sourceState;
        DestinationState = destinationState;
        ConditionalIntent = conditionalIntent;
    }
}
```

But all I get is an error, that FieldState cannot be cast to `IState<Itransition>`. Do I really have to manually cast this in the constructor implementation or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You need your `IState`-interface to be covariant, this is my making it´s generic argument `<out T>`.

Comment: Thanks. I have read about it now after your post. That fixed it. Thank you very much :)